# Python GPXPy speed data is missing

Tags: python, gpx

I am trying to get data from a GPX file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creator="Kurviger.de" version="1.1" xmlns:gh="https://kurviger.de/public/schema/gpx/1.1">
<metadata>
<link href="https://">
<text>text</text>
</link>
<time>2021-12-21T14:53:19Z</time>
</metadata>
<trk>
<name>data.gpx</name>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="55.015102" lon="15.275796"><speed>55.987000</speed><time>2021-12-21T14:53:19Z</time><desc>1</desc></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="55.015224" lon="15.275687"><speed>55.987000</speed><time>2021-12-21T14:53:19Z</time><desc>1</desc></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="55.015358" lon="15.275580"><speed>55.987000</speed><time>2021-12-21T14:53:19Z</time><desc>1</desc></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="55.015495" lon="15.275477"><speed>55.987000</speed><time>2021-12-21T14:53:19Z</time><desc>1</desc></trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

As you can see the speed information is given in the gpx file.

To read the data (longitude, latitude, elevation and speed) if seperated the track points like this:

```
gpx_file = open("route.gpx", "r")
gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)

data = gpx.tracks[0].segments[0].points
```

As longitude, latitude, elevation are extracted correctly the speed information isnt. If i try to print it (for the first point for example but the issue can be found at all points):

```
print(data[0].speed)
```

`None` will be printed.

Can anybody help?

Comment: The docs at https://pypi.org/project/gpxpy/ have some things to say about gpx1.1 and speed, "GPX 1.0 specified a speed attribute for every track point, but that was removed in GPX 1.1."

Comment: thank you for your comment. Yes but in the parse function ia the following comment `version may be '1.0', '1.1' or None (then it will be read from the gpx
    xml node if possible, if not then version 1.0 will be used).` So I think it should use gpx 1.0 and read the speed data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Gui LeFlea
I tried

```
gpxpy.parse(gpx_file,version="1.0")
```

and this did the job.